# Convert async/await style to traditional .then style

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, bluebird

Consider the following code example, I will attempt to get the result in two ways, if `methodA` does not give me the expected result, I will try `methodB`.

```
function methodA () {
    console.log('called A');
    return Promise.resolve('not result');
}

function methodB () {
    console.log('called B');
    return Promise.resolve('result');
}

function isValid (result) {
    return result === 'result';
}

async function getResult () {
  let result = await methodA();
  if (!isValid(result)) result = await methodB();
  console.log('result', result);
}
```

I want to use the traditional `.then` style to handle the async functions.

```
function getResult () {
  return methodA()
  .then((result) => {
    if (isValid(result)) return result;
    return methodB();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('result', result);
  });
}
```

I may add more methods (`methodC`, `methodD`...) in the future.

Is there a way to make `getResult` look cleaner?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkrb87Lo/5/)

Comment: Do you care which result that you use? e.g. do you always need to check A before B before C?

Comment: Also, just curious is `async` / `await` causing issues somewhere? What is the impetus for switching to Promise chaining?

Comment: The async/await syntax was made for the sole reason to make things look cleaner (and to make promises easier to use for newcomers to JS). There isn't much you can do with this to make it look cleaner other than remove braces from one-liners and possibly turn that if into a one-liner ternary.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, Yes. For example, if A works, no further executions, otherwise try B, C, D and so on.

Comment: I believe async/await will work most of the time, but I just need to use some `bluebird` methods at some point, therefore I hope to return a `bluebird`'s `Promise` in `getResult`. On other hand, I don't like the `try {} catch {}` syntax very much personally.

Comment: Hmm, well I thought that Promise.any might be your best best but if the order matters then you would need Promise.all or to chain them as you do now. The unfortunate side effect of Promise.all is it  doesn't shortcut if any earlier promise resolves

Comment: `Promise.any` could be an answer, but does not actually suit the case, because it will trigger all the methods.

Comment: Why not do `Bluebird.resolve(getResult())` to get a Bluebird promise from the native promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve promises one after another (in sequence):

```js
function methodA() {
  console.log('called A');
  return Promise.resolve('not result');
}

function methodB() {
  console.log('called B');
  return Promise.resolve('result');
}

function methodC() {
  console.log('called С');
  return Promise.resolve('not result');
}

function getResult() {
  let methods = [methodA, methodB, methodC];

  let op = Promise.resolve();
  methods.forEach(m => op = op.then(result => result == 'result' ? null : m()));

  return op.then(() => console.log('result'));
}

getResult();
```

In the example above only `methodA` and `methodB` will be called.

Comment: Downvoter please explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is a hater :).

Comment: Yeah, the question and my answer were downvoted too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function methodA() {
    console.log('called A');
    return Promise.resolve('not result');
}

function methodB() {
    console.log('called B');
    return Promise.reject({ error: true, reason: 'idk' });
}

function methodC() {
    console.log('called C');
    return Promise.resolve('not result');
}

function methodD() {
    console.log('called D');
    return Promise.resolve('result');
}

function addFallback(promise, nextMethod) {
    return promise
    .then(result => result === 'result' ? result : nextMethod())
}

function getResult () {
    let promise = methodA()
    promise = addFallback(promise, methodB);
    promise = addFallback(promise, methodC);
    promise = addFallback(promise, methodD);
    return promise
    .then(result => {
        if (result) { console.log('result', result); }
    });
}

getResult()
.catch(e => { console.log(e)});
```

Comment: What if any of methods will throw error? All the rest `catch` handlers will be called, but error won't be handled.

Comment: Does the SO need to handle the errors, or does is the right way to handle the errors just calling a fallback method?  It changes the answer...

Comment: Only the next catch handler would be called, btw... not all the rest of them.

Comment: In OP examples the thrown error can be handled outside of `getResult ` function (in both cases with `async/await` and with regular promises) in your example - not.

Comment: I think using .catch for flow control is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I would argue that in the case described, an invalid response *is* an error, that requires error handling -- which is a fallback function call.

Comment: Updated my answer to maintain semantics of OP's getResult() function.

Answer (score 0):

- Have a look at  [babel-plugin-transform-async-to-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-promises)
- [There's also a PR to include it in core](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/7076)